# Relation between transport functor of a fibration and a Hurewicz connection on it

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $A\overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow}B$ be a (Hurewicz) fibration.

- The homotopy lifting property w.r.t a fiber $\alpha ^{-1}(b)$
  furnishes for each path $b\to b^\prime$ in the base a continuous map
  $\alpha ^{-1}(b)\to \alpha ^{-1}(b^\prime)$. Moreover, this
  assignment extends to a functor $\pi_1B\longrightarrow
     \mathsf{hTop}$.
- On the other hand, as a fibration $\begin{smallmatrix}A\\\downarrow\\B\end{smallmatrix}$ admits a [Hurewicz connection](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+connection) $s$. Given such a connection it is tempting to send a path $b\overset{\gamma}{\to} b^\prime $ in the base to the following set function (analogously to covering space theory) $$\alpha^{-1}(b)\longrightarrow \alpha ^{-1}(b^\prime),\quad a\mapsto \operatorname{eval}_1s(a,\gamma).$$ I suspect this set function might be continuous, but I see no reason for it to be a homotopy equivalence, since $s(a,\gamma)$ need not be related in a nice way to lifts of opposite path $b\overset{\bar\gamma}{\leftarrow} b^\prime $.

**Questions.**

1. Is fiber transport along a Hurewicz connection continuous?
2. (Assuming continuity) Is fiber transport along a Hurewicz connection functorial?
3. (Assuming continuity) Does it coincide with the first transfer functor?
4. Suppose the fibers are all homeomorphic. Are there any interesting conditions that make the transport functor $\pi_1B\longrightarrow \mathsf{hTop}$ lift to $\mathsf{Top}$? That is, can we obtain such homeomorphisms via transport?

---

I thought about possible functoriality of the transport along the Hurewicz connection. We want $\operatorname{eval}_1(a,\delta \ast \gamma)=\operatorname{eval}_1s(\operatorname{eval}_1s(a,\gamma),\delta,)$. We may consider the concatenation $s(\operatorname{eval}_1s(a,\gamma),\delta)\ast s(a,\gamma)$ which seems to lift $\delta \ast \gamma$, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

**Added.** [Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330354/69037) to MO.